# Connection string from EA to nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, database-connection, connection-string, enterprise-architect

I'm writing addin to EA and I have problem with connection string.
How to use connection string from `EA.Repository` in nHibernate? Or how to extract connection details from EA.
I can have `user id`, `db type` but for example I don't know how to extract name of database.

Answer (score 2):

DBMS connection strings are tough beasts to tame, because the format is extensible and thus in order to parse one properly you need to take into account whatever extensions the various DBMS providers have thought to implement. EA doesn't make matters any easier, and in fact overloads the connection strings.

You can retrieve what EA refers to as a connection string from the `Repository.ConnectionString` property. In the case of an EAP file, this is simply the file name. In the DBMS case, it is a string on the form `EAConnectString:<name> --- DBType=<type_nr>;Connect=<connection_string>`.

`<name>` is a symbolic name which can be anything at all, it is not required or guaranteed to be the name of a specific database. `<type_nr>` is EA's internal numeric identity for the DBMS type. These are undocumented, but can be sussed out with a bit of testing. `Repository.RepositoryType()` might help there. `<connection_string>`, finally, is the DBMS connection string.

So if you chop off everything up to and including `Connect=` you should end up with a connection string that ODBC will recognize. Inside this "proper" connection string you'll find `Data Source=<source>` and `Initial Catalog=<db_name>`. `<source>` is typically a server and a port, and `<db_name>` is the name of the database.

Note that EA supports "lazy loading" mode when connecting to a DBMS. In this mode, contents of the database are only read when they're needed (ie, when expanding a node in the project browser or opening a diagram). If the repository has been opened in this mode, the connection string **ends** with `LazyLoad=1;`, so you need to chop that out too.